# redmine - updating a list type custom field failed

Tags: python, redmine

I'm trying to update a list type custom field, with json like

```
{'id': xx, "name": "xxxx", "multiple": True, 
 'value': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']}]
```

I sent request using python-redmine. And our redmine version is 4.1.1.stable.

Python code:

```
redmine.project.update(xx, 
                       custom_fields=[{'id': xx, "name": "xxxx", "multiple": True, 
                       'value': ['new_string1', 'new_string2', 'new_string3']}])
```

Python gave me below error, and the value failed to update. Tried various ways to input the value, but no luck. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/solidfire/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/psirt-tools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redminelib/managers/base.py", line 248, in update
    response = self.redmine.engine.request(self.resource_class.http_method_update, url, data=request)
  File "/Users/solidfire/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/psirt-tools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redminelib/engines/base.py", line 87, in request
    return self.process_response(self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/solidfire/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/envs/psirt-tools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redminelib/engines/base.py", line 182, in process_response
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(', '.join(': '.join(e) if isinstance(e, list) else e for e in errors))
redminelib.exceptions.ValidationError: <field name> is not included in the list
```

Comment: Solved. It turned out that one of the values in the list does not exist in the pre-defined list for that field.